# How does the DHCP server sort the MAC addresses according to the physical order of the clients?

Tags: linux, dhcp, macintosh

There are hundreds of servers, one of which serves as a DHCP server.

The hosts file of the DHCP server specifies the IP address and host name for each client server. But the MAC address of the client server is not known.

All client servers are diskless systems and are started by pxe. After startup, the MAC address of the client server and the IP address obtained through DHCP are automatically collected and sent to the DHCP server.

When we first start all the client servers, how does the DHCP server sort the MAC addresses according to the physical order of the clients?

---

I need to elaborate on this problem again.

In fact, I can't clearly describe my problem.

In a cabinet, the name of the server is node0, node1, node2... From top to bottom.
When all the nodes start up through PXE for the first time (all nodes start at one time, regardless of the order), use DHCP to get the IP address of ethernet. These nodes then automatically collect MAC addresses and send them to the server. Previously, the server did not know the MAC address information of these nodes.

When we get MAC information sent from the client, which may not correspond to the server name (node0, node1...), we need to manually modify the dhcpd.conf file to bind the IP address to the server name (node0, node1...) the next time we boot.

I want it to be done automatically, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "physical order of the clients"?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but many DHCP servers actually require all MAC addresses in the configuration file (see e.g. `man dhcpd.conf`) if you want to treat them differently than other machines. So, for this kind of usage, "the MAC address of the client server is not known" doesn't apply.

Comment: There is no such thing as physical order of the clients. If you mean order of allocated IP addresses, it depends on DHCP server. Some servers allocate addresses in increasing order (*.101, *.102,...), some in decreasing order. But it is always first come first serve.

Comment: ”physical order of the clients“ is ”The order in which servers are stored in cabinets“

Comment: In the following reply, I will elaborate on this question again.

Comment: Be sure to use the "edit" link on your Question instead of the Answer box; thank you!

Comment: Let me try and guess what you want. You have a cabinet with say 8 machines in it which you boot using PXE. You want to call the machines node0, node1, ... node7. You do not know in advance the MAC addresses of the machines. You want to call the machine at the top (or left) of the cabinet node0, the one next to it node1 (the "physical order" in your question). You want to power on all the machines at the same time. You are willing to do an initial boot, then some magic that you hope this site can help you with, then a final reboot to get to this state. Is this a reasonable summary?

Comment: Assuming you have enough addresses in the pool, DHCP by default gives each client a new address, and keeps the addresses same for each client, so you might not _need_ to configure anything to have a constant address for each client. (Though this will break if you ever swap enough devices so that the DHCP server needs to reuse addresses.)

Answer (score 1):

> In a cabinet, the name of the server is node0, node1, node2... From top to bottom. When all the nodes start up through PXE for the first time (all nodes start at one time, regardless of the order), use DHCP to get the IP address of ethernet.

Actually, PXE involves DHCP. So what happens is that each node already has a MAC address (however this MAC address got assigned). The node then uses that MAC address to broadcast a DHCP request. The DHCP server can recognize the MAC address, and sends back the TFTP server address to allow the node to get the PXE image, as well as the IP address for the node.

> These nodes then automatically collect MAC addresses and send them to the server. Previously, the server did not know the MAC address information of these nodes.

I am not sure which server you are talking about. Maybe you have an additional server that collects the MAC address, and they have a custom step in the boot process which sends those MAC addresses to this server?

Anyhow, the **DHCP server** gets the MAC address from the DHCP broadcast request. This happens *before* they get the PXE image. If the DHCP server wants to do anything special with the MAC address, like selecting the right PXE image, this MAC address *must be mentioned in the DHCP configuration files*.

If the question is "how do I find the MAC address for a given physical node?", you either need to look at the configuration of the node (sometimes the MAC address is a parameter for Uboot etc.), or you need to disconnect the node from the LAN, connect it to some other computer, boot it, and record the MAC address in the DHCP broadcast request.